# How to call a function with a keyboard without focusing on any textbox?

Tags: javascript, html

I know how to trigger a function with a textbox:

```
<input onkeyup="if (event.keyCode == 13) check(this)" type="text">
```

But what if I'm not focused on any textboxes, but I still need to call a js function with a space button for example?

Particular context:
I'm trying to write an interactive test, and I want users to be able to switch to the next question not only with the button on the page:

```
<button id="nextButton" onclick="nextQuestion()">Next</button>
```

but also with a space button, so they can change questions more quickly. To arrange that, I need to call the **nextQuestion()** function everytime a user presses space on a keyboard.

Comment: bind events to the window.

Comment: `window.addEventListener("keyup", (function(e){ if(e.keyCode == 32) nextQuestion()})); `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try binding the event to the window

```
window.onkeyup = function(event){
  if (event.keyCode== 32) nextQuestion() 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With jquery you can do something like

```
$(window).keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 32 || e.keyCode == 0) {
   nextQuestion()
  }
});
```

or if you prefer vanilla javascript i recommend

```
window.addEventListener("keyup", keyPressed(e));

function keyPressed(e) {
   if(e.keyCode == 32) nextQuestion();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can call **keyup** on **body tag** or **window object**

```
 $("body").keyup(function(event){
      alert("KeyCode is : " + event.keyCode);
      if(e.keyCode == 32){ nextQuestion()}
    });
```